# how to create labels for YOLO-V1 , target bounding box while implementing from scratch?

Tags: object, deep-learning, computer-vision, detection, yolo

I'm trying to implement YOLO-V1，but I got some problem when create labels.
YOLO-V1 has 2 bounding box, so, when a grid has an object, how to choose which bounding box to put location information?
For example:
Follow YOLO paper, normalized location of an object in a grid is [0.5, 0.8,.7, 0.9]
how to prepare this 1x1x30 tensor[image]?? More specif[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWiDf.png)ically label for Bounding box-2 ??
This  is for labelling not for testing!!!
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element in each boundary is 0 or 1 which refers to the existence of an object in this boundary box ( the cell called p in your picture). The loss function changes depending on p according like this: [image: this] so if p is 0 it doesn't consider the locations at all.

It's implemented this way to be able to detect overlapping objects in the same box as illustrated in this image [image: here]

Comment: So this second bounding box will be used only for overlapping objects and if my dataset has no overlapping object this second bounding box  coordinates will be zeros for all targets?

Comment: That's right, the important thing is that `p` of the second box must be 0 if there is no object in that box